# Is it proper to put http error message in custom header?

Tags: rest, http, http-headers

What I meant by *http error message* is a brief error reason for users.

What I made with php BE and node FE is:

```
// php API server
http_response_code(400);
// encode in case the message contains non-ascii characters
$errorMsg = rawurlencode("Parameter foo is missing");
header("error-message: {$errorMsg}"); // the header containing error message
die();

// node client
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (res: AxiosResponse) => res,
  (err: unknown) => {
    if (axios.isAxiosError(err)) {
      if (err.response) {
        // the header containing error message
        const errorMsg = err.response.headers["error-message"];
        err.message = errorMsg ? decodeURIComponent(errorMsg) : err.message;
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(err);
  },
);
```

Is this proper in the sense of extension (eg. header rule might change in the future)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it proper to put http error message in custom header?

It's an odd choice; we already have a standardized mechanism for sharing error messages with the client -- the response body

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

Note that you cannot expect a *general purpose* HTTP component to understand your custom header.  Unless you are going to go through the work of registering it, it is only going to be useful to bespoke components who learn about it out of band.  So it runs a bit contrary to the "uniform interface" constraint.

(That said, it shouldn't cause any problems either -- intermediaries are supposed to ignore and forward unknown fields; see [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-5.1)).